# unable to apply a function on every img within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, pixastic

i'm trying to blur every image within a DIV, but for no reason, it just doesn't work

```
<div id="textarea"  >random HTML with imgs</div>
                         <script type="text/javascript">
                            var arraysOfImgs = $('#textarea').find('img').map(function(){
                                return this.id;
                            }).get();
                            for (var i = 0; i < arraysOfImgs.length; i++){
                                Pixastic.process(arraysOfImgs[i], "blurfast", {
                                    amount : '1.5'
                                });
                            }

                        </script>';
```

even this didn't work out

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                         $(document).ready(function() {
                            var arraysOfImgs = $('#textarea').find(\'img\').map(function(){
                                return this.id;
                            }).get();

                            $.each(arraysOfImgs, function() {
                                Pixastic.process(this, "blurfast", {
                                    amount : '1.5'
                                });
                            });
                        }); 
                        </script>
```

no error is being shown, nothing happens when i load the page...

EDIT : no more php echo..

Comment: This looks like PHP, how about you put this in a HTML file and open it in Firefox and debug it with FireBug or with Google Chrome

Comment: Guy, this is what JS should NOT look like. First, extract it out or your PHP code. Second, use jQuery each instead of for loop (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I think is that you're passing the images' ID values. Pixastic (if it's [this one](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/)) needs the image element.

Your code might look like this:

```
$('#textarea img').each(function() {
    Pixastic.process(this, "blurfast", {
        amount : '1.5'
    });
});
```

---

Note also that Pixastic provides a jQuery plugin, so you can just do this:

```
$('#textarea img').pixastic('blurfast', {amount: 1.5});
```

Comment: simply effective !, gracias !

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
      var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    Pixastic.process(img, "blur");
}
document.body.appendChild(img);
img.src = "myimage.jpg";
```

and embeded blur.js ( http://www.pixastic.com/lib/git/pixastic/actions/blur.js )